# How to write Japanese characters in excel using poi in java?

Tags: java, excel, character-encoding, apache-poi

I am using POI to write excel sheet but i am facing trouble when i try to write japanese character in excel.some ascii characters will be printed instead of japanese . i tried it in many way to solve but i can't. can any one help me.

Here is my code.

```
public void readExcel() throws IOException {

   workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
   worksheet = workbook.createSheet("FieldCount");

   HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
   font.setColor(HSSFFont.COLOR_RED);
   font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

   // Create the style
   HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   cellStyle.setFont(font);

   HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow(0);
   HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short)0);
   cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
   cellA1.setCellValue("Object Type");

   HSSFCell cellA2 = row1.createCell((short)1);
   cellA2.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
   cellA2.setCellValue("Object Name");

   HSSFCell cellA3 = row1.createCell((short)2);
   cellA3.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   cellA3.setCellValue("Script");
   HSSFCell cellA4 = row1.createCell((short)3);
   cellA4.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   cellA4.setCellValue("Available Script");
   HSSFCell cellA5 = row1.createCell((short)4);
   cellA5.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   cellA5.setCellValue("Caption");

   i = 1;
}

public void writexsl(Fields fields) {
   System.out.println("\n" + i + "\n");
   try {
      HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow(i);

      HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short)0);
      cellA1.setCellValue(fields.ObjectType);
      HSSFCell cellA2 = row1.createCell((short)1);
      cellA2.setCellValue(fields.ObjectName);
      HSSFCell cellA3 = row1.createCell((short)2);
      cellA3.setCellValue(fields.Script);
      HSSFCell cellA4 = row1.createCell((short)3);
      cellA4.setCellValue(fields.ScriptValue);
      HSSFCell cellA5 = row1.createCell((short)4);
      //fields.Cation = URLEncoder.encode(fields.Cation, "UTF-8");
      //fields.Cation = URLDecoder.decode(fields.Cation, "UTF-8"); 

      cellA5.setCellValue(fields.Cation);
      System.out.println("Caption Japanese" + cellA5.getStringCellValue());
      i++;
      System.out.println("write columns");
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("error" + e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the very latest version of Apache POI? And did you ensure that the Japanese characters are correctly getting into your Java code?

Comment: Ya i got it. after upgrade the version of poi to v3.9 i got the japanese character in excel . Thank u ..

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
HSSFRichTextString s = new HSSFRichTextString(str);
cell.setCellValue(s);
```

and the excel files that are created using this technique does contain UTF-16 characters.